# Best approach to process a grid like image

Tags: python, opencv

Hello stackoverflow community,

If I had a grid-like paper which was to be scanned and then converted to an image(png) such as the following [Grid-Paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2wG0.png).
Within each cell, we can find a symbol. How or what would we best way to extract each and one of those cells (themselves made into an image for instance).

I heard of open-cv and so I was wondering if with this library there was a common way to extract content within cell-like shapes.

Thank you for your time,
Phil.

Comment: That is a good starting point... You can post a new question once you have a specific programming problem. Please see [ask]

Comment: I see, thank for your trouble Miki. Much appreciated.